# Beginner Ruby / MSQL Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

http://localhost:3000/genre

I'm using Instant Rails, I'm introducing scaffolding for the first time ever.

So everything looks like its working fine, I did my own RoR page etc, today i come in today and when I go to localhost:3000 I get the following error message:

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3000

Any suggestions of what I should check would be greatly appreciated. So far I know to confirm that:

1. the windows host file connects 127.0.0.1 to localhost

I've had an update to this the Mongrel server doesnt start properly with the new app I have created, rather than an open window, it just runs a script and closes the window without confirmation that it has started.

Thanks in advance.

here is the details of the Mongrel error:

C:\Users\Will\Desktop\instantrails\rails_apps\talewiki>mongrel_rails start -p 30
00
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3000
** Starting Rails with development environment...
C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.0.
2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:217
:in `establish_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord
::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/acti
verecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specifi
cation.rb:208:in`establish_connection'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rail
s-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:234:in `initialize_database'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rail
s-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:94:in`process'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rail
s-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:49:in `send'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rail
s-2.0.2/lib/initializer.rb:49:in`run'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/rails_apps/talewiki/config/envir
onment.rb:13
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems/custom_require.rb:27:in`require'
         ... 9 levels...
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mong
rel-1.1.2-x86-mswin32/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mong
rel-1.1.2-x86-mswin32/bin/mongrel_rails:281
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in`lo
ad'
        from C:/Users/Will/Desktop/instantrails/ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19

Comment: Could you share with us your exception log?

Comment: Hi Snehal,

Thanks for the response.  I have the following logs:

Apache Error
Apache Access
MySQL Error
Instant Rails

Where do I find the exception log?

Thanks again.

Comment: The log is normally in log/development.log with in your rails app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears your Database has not been configured. Check out the APP_ROOT/config/database.yml file and find if you have created the database that corresponds to the development environment. Once you setup the DB, your code should run fine.

Comment: Looks to be set-up fine.

I havent set a username of password.

Should the username and password be:

u/n: root
pass: (blank)

?

Comment: Sorted it, it was an error with the tutorial I was following, format for the connection should be:

development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_name_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: localhost

Thanks for your help Snehal

Comment: @WANNABE: can you post a link to the tutorial?